# Can you use python to access PowerPoint add in functions?

Tags: python, powerpoint

I am creating multiple powerpoint decks that have data modified but I need to be able to hit this "refresh slides" button that accesses the updated data from a connected website. Is there a way to do this automatically in python?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

No, there is not. However, there is a workaround:

1. You have to put your data in single .xslx (Excel) files
2. Use this data within you PowerPointPresentation (see [here](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/insert-excel-data-in-powerpoint-0690708a-5ce6-41b4-923f-11d57554138d) for a description)
3. Write a script to refresh your data and output them into the .xlsx files
4. If you have done everything correctly, next time you open PowerPoint it will ask you, whether or not it should refresh the tables/graphs.

That is the only work around I have found in order to refresh PowerPointPresentations.